# How to disable `apt-daily.service` on Ubuntu cloud VM image?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, cloud-init

The Ubuntu 16.04 server VM image apparently starts the "apt-daily.service" every
12 hours or so; this service performs various APT-related tasks like refreshing
the list of available packages, performing unattended upgrades if needed, etc.

When starting from a VM "snapshot", the service is triggered *immediately*, as (I
presume) systemd realizes quickly that the timer should have gone off long ago.

However, a running APT prevents other `apt` processes from running as it holds a
lock on `/var/lib/dpkg`. The error message indicating this looks like this:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

I need to disable this automated APT task until Ansible
has completed the machine setup (which typically involves installing packages);
see https://github.com/gc3-uzh-ch/elasticluster/issues/304 for more info and
context.

I have tried various options to disable the "unattended upgrades" feature
through a "user data" script for `cloud-init`, but all of them have failed so
far.

### 1. Disable the systemd task

systemd task `apt-daily.service` is triggered by `apt-daily.timer`. I have tried
to disable one or the other, or both, with various cobinations of the following
commands; still, the `apt-daily.service` is started moments after the VM becomes
ready to accept SSH connections::

```
    #!/bin/bash

    systemctl stop apt-daily.timer
    systemctl disable apt-daily.timer
    systemctl mask apt-daily.service
    systemctl daemon-reload
```

### 2. Disable config option `APT::Periodic::Enable`

Script `/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily` reads a few APT configuration
variables; the setting `APT::Periodic::Enable` disables the functionality
altogether (lines 331--337). I have tried disabling it with the following
script::

```
    #!/bin/bash

    # cannot use /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic as suggested in
    # /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily, as Ubuntu distributes the
    # unattended upgrades stuff with priority 20 and 50 ...
    # so override everything with a 99xxx file
    cat > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99elasticluster <<__EOF
    APT::Periodic::Enable "0";
    // undo what's in 20auto-upgrade
    APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
    APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
    __EOF
```

However, despite `APT::Periodic::Enable` having value `0` from the command line
(see below), the `unattended-upgrades` program is still run...

```
    ubuntu@test:~$ apt-config shell AutoAptEnable APT::Periodic::Enable
    AutoAptEnable='0'
```

### 3. Remove `/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily` altogether

The following `cloud-init` script removes the unattended upgrades script
altogether::

```
    #!/bin/bash

    mv /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily.DISABLED
```

Still, the task runs and I can see it in the process table! although the file
does not exist if probed from the command line::

```
ubuntu@test:~$ ls /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily': No such file or directory
```

It looks as though the `cloud-init` script (together with the SSH command-line)
and the root systemd process execute in separate filesystems and process
spaces...

### Questions

Is there something obvious I am missing?  Or is there some namespace magic going
on which I am not aware of?

Most importantly: how can I disable the `apt-daily.service` through a
`cloud-init` script?

Comment: This isn't going to help you until it gets rolled into an official package update, but please see the [patch I just posted to Debian bug #844453](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=844453#10).

Comment: Maybe you were missing the `--now` flag in the `systemctl disable` command in order to make the change effective immediately. That was my issue.

Comment: @DanielF no, because `disable --now` is equivalent to `stop` followed by `disable`.

Comment: Apparently this has been *FINALLY* fixed in systemd in 2019 Feb: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5659. So hopefully it will be in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes, there was something obvious that I was missing.

Systemd is all about concurrent start of services, so the `cloud-init` script is
run *at the same time* the `apt-daily.service` is triggered. By the time
`cloud-init` gets to execute the user-specified payload, `apt-get update` is
already running. So the attempts 2. and 3. failed not because of some namespace
magic, but because they altered the system too late for `apt.systemd.daily` to
pick the changes up.

This also means that there is basically no way of *preventing*
`apt.systemd.daily` from running -- one can only kill it after it's started.

This "user data" script takes this route::

```
#!/bin/bash

systemctl stop apt-daily.service
systemctl kill --kill-who=all apt-daily.service

# wait until `apt-get updated` has been killed
while ! (systemctl list-units --all apt-daily.service | egrep -q '(dead|failed)')
do
  sleep 1;
done

# now proceed with own APT tasks
apt install -y python
```

There is still a time window during which SSH logins are possible yet `apt-get`
will not run, but I cannot imagine another solution that can works on the stock
Ubuntu 16.04 cloud image.

Comment: this worked for me on aws ubuntu 16.04, thanks for the solution

Comment: Yes, I am going the road of creating a custom AMI. This also speeds up the installation of common services.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be enough, I find there are still straggling instances of `apt-get -o Acquire::http::AllowRedirect=false update`

Answer (score 22):

Note: Unfortunately part of the solution below **doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04 systems** (such as that of the questioner) because the suggested `systemd-run` invocation only works on **Ubuntu 18.04 and above** (see the [comments for details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315502/how-to-disable-apt-daily-service-on-ubuntu-cloud-vm-image/480986?noredirect=1#comment883390_480986)). I'll leave the answer here because this question is still a popular hit regardless of which Ubuntu version you are using...

On Ubuntu 18.04 (and up) there may be up to two services involved in boot time apt updating/upgrading. The first `apt-daily.service` refreshes the list of packages. However there can be a second `apt-daily-upgrade.service` which actually installs security critical packages. An [answer to the "Terminate and disable/remove unattended upgrade before command returns"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463503/109111) question gives an excellent example of how to wait for both of these to finish (copied here for convenience):

```
systemd-run --property="After=apt-daily.service apt-daily-upgrade.service" --wait /bin/true
```

(note this has to be run as root). If you are trying to disable these services on future boots you will need to mask BOTH services:

```
systemctl mask apt-daily.service apt-daily-upgrade.service
```

Alternatively you can `systemctl disable` both services AND their associated timers (i.e. `apt-daily.timer` and `apt-daily-upgrade.timer`).

Note the masking/disabling techniques in this answer only prevent the update/upgrade on future boots - they won't stop them if they are already running in the current boot.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you!  Although, note that `systemd-run` on Ubuntu 16.04 is too old to support the `--wait` option, but it should not really be necessary for the purpose at hand. (According to the man page, `--wait` waits for the *termination* of a unit but it's enough to wait for its start which is the default behavior of `systemd-run`.)

Comment: I stand corrected: the given `systemd-run` incantation does *not* work on Ubuntu 16.04 at all; it dies with error message *Unknown assignment After=apt-daily.service apt-daily-upgrade.service*.  It looks like some unit properties were not available in `systemd-run`, see for example [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4402)

Comment: @riccardo-murri you got me :-)! I was actually wondering about 16.04/18.04 differences myself (hence the weaselly "up to two") and then forgot to put the caveat in. What change would you suggest?

Comment: @riccardo-murri ah that's too bad I'll add a big warning to the top of the answer saying it can't be used on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Disabled the services and restarted and it works!

Comment: would there be any equivalent that could work on ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 7):

You can disable this via the "bootcmd" cloud-init module.  This runs before network is brought up, which is required before apt update can get a chance to run.

```
#cloud-config
bootcmd:
    - echo 'APT::Periodic::Enable "0";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10cloudinit-disable
    - apt-get -y purge update-notifier-common ubuntu-release-upgrader-core landscape-common unattended-upgrades
    - echo "Removed APT and Ubuntu 18.04 garbage early" | systemd-cat
```

Once you ssh into the instance, you should also wait for the final phases of cloud-init to finish, since it moves apt sources / lists around.

```
# Wait for cloud-init to finish moving apt sources.list around... 
# a good source of random failures
# Note this is NOT a replacement for also disabling apt updates via bootcmd
while [ ! -f /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished ]; do
    echo 'Waiting for cloud-init to finish...'
    sleep 3
done
```

This is also helpful to see how early the bootcmd runs:

```
# Show microseconds in systemd journal
journalctl -r -o short-precise
```

You can verify this worked as follows:

```
apt-config dump | grep Periodic

# Verify nothing was updated until we run apt update ourselves.
cd /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo du -sh .   # small size
ls -ltr         # old timestamps
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on Anon's solution, I created this script, which after being run and then rebooting, solves the problem for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

systemctl mask apt-daily.service apt-daily-upgrade.service
systemctl disable apt-daily.service apt-daily-upgrade.service
systemctl disable apt-daily.timer apt-daily-upgrade.timer
```

Answer (score 2):

Woudn't ist be easier to mask the unit

```
systemctl mask apt-daily.service
```

?

Comment: Doesn't work -- see section *1. Disable the systemd task* in the question's text. But thanks anyway for the suggestion! :-)

Comment: disable and mask a service is not the same. mask create a Link to /dev/null.  `ls -al /etc/systemd/system/ | grep alsa
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Sep  1 13:17 alsa-init.service -> /dev/null`
the Data is empty.

Comment: i get rid unattended upgrade `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades` and forbit it. So the status of unit apt-daily.service is dead.

Comment: Hi @Bahamut thanks for your efforts!  The question, however, is how to disable `apt-daily.service` from a `cloud-init` script *and* before it starts after VM reboot: this means: (1) it must be done non-interactively, (2) it must be done before `apt-daily.service` fires for the first time.  (If my understanding of systemd is correct, (2) *cannot* actually be accomplished as `cloud-init` and `apt-daily` run concurrently -- see my own reply for more.)

Comment: I tried this on a normal physical machine (i.e. not a VM) and can confirm it doesn't work. You need to at also stop the timer: systemctl stop apt-daily.timer; systemctl disable apt-daily.timer

Comment: On a physical machine this do indeed disable the service: `sudo systemctl stop apt-daily.timer;sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.timer;sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.service;sudo systemctl stop apt-daily-upgrade.timer;sudo systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.timer;sudo systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.service`

Answer (score 2):

This cloud-init works.

```
#cloud-config
apt:
  conf: |
    APT {
      Periodic {
        Update-Package-Lists "0";
      };
    };
    Unattended-Upgrade {
      Package-Blacklist {
        "*";
      };
    };
runcmd:
  - [ systemctl, stop, apt-daily.timer, apt-daily-upgrade.timer ]
  - [ systemctl, disable, apt-daily.timer, apt-daily-upgrade.timer ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The excellent answers on here have been working for me for ages but suddenly I started getting the dreaded

```
{"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation"}
```

from Ansible again

I'm running an Ubuntu 20.04 AWS image in EC2, the issue turned out to be that since 16.04 the [AWS SSM-agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/agent-install-ubuntu.html) is included by default as a snap package and snap runs on it's own update schedule. SSM-agent was trying to update at the exact time I was trying to do an apt update. There are [various options](https://snapcraft.io/docs/keeping-snaps-up-to-date) to change the update schedule for snap or put it on hold for up to 60 days but it seems like it ignores whatever you say for the first update and will still cause instance provisioning to fail.

The only thing that worked for me was to run:

```
snap disable amazon-ssm-agent
```

as the first command in the instance user-data

and:

```
snap enable amazon-ssm-agent
```

as the last

It took me a long time to work this out

**[ update ]**

disabling snap will fail if the snap update is already running, this worked for me

```
i=0
while ! snap disable amazon-ssm-agent; do
  echo 'attempting to disable snap...' $i
  sleep 2
  ((i=i+1))
  if [ $i -gt 10 ]; then
    echo unable to disable snap..
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

what a mess

Answer (score 1):

This waits for 1sec in a whil loop and checks if the lock is released.

```
while : ; do
                sleep 1
                echo $( ps aux | grep -c lock_is_held ) processes are using apt.
                ps aux | grep -i apt
                [[ $( ps aux | grep -c lock_is_held ) > 2 ]] || break
        done
        echo Apt released
```

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is to provision the machine without incurring in a locking error, the simplest and most stable solution is to run the provisioner remote command (or the apt-related commands) while locking the apt-daily lock file. No service masking/disabling/waiting etc.etc.

In Ubuntu server, the package update programs (apt-daily, unattended-upgrades, cloud-init), go through apt-daily, so the solution can be centered on it.

Apt-daily uses `flock(2)` locks, which, differently from dpkg/apt (which use `fnctl`), can be managed via a commandline tool, with the convienience that it supports waiting on the lock.

Therefore if one, for example, uses Chef, it's as simple as running, on the nodes:

```bsh
$ sudo flock /var/lib/apt/daily_lock chef-client
```

and:

- either chef-client will grab the lock first, and any apt-daily-based service will wait;
- or any apt-daily-based service will lock it first, then chef-clien will wait, and finally run once apt-daily completes.

If the provisioner is not invoked on the nodes, it's possible to modify the provisioner configuration (eg. Ansible playbook) to run:

```bsh
$ sudo flock /var/lib/apt/daily_lock apt update
$ sudo flock /var/lib/apt/daily_lock apt upgrade
```

(or any variation, like `sh -c '...'` and so on)

Source: https://saveriomiroddi.github.io/Handling-the-apt-lock-on-ubuntu-server-installations.