# some other process automatically locks /var/lib/dpkg/lock for few minutes when restarting my system.

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, lock

I am running Debian buster a.k.a. Debian testing. From the last couple of weeks, whenever I reboot the sytem i.e. going to CTRL+ALT+F1 and run

```
$ sudo reboot
```

it reboots the systems as normally but when it comees to on the desktop after logging in, I always get -

```
$ sudo aptitude autoclean
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
Freed 0 B of disk space
```

and I have to wait around 5 minutes before I can run the command. It can't be memory or system constraints as free shows -

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        634M        6.3G         94M        726M        6.8G
Swap:           59G          0B         59G
```

and can't be the chip as it's a pretty new Skylake i5 5400

Answer (score 3):

See what process has the file open with `lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock` or `fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock`.

Chances are that it's the apt-daily service, which normally runs once a day to run `apt-get update` and notify the user of available updates. If you don't like this, see [How to disable `apt-daily.service` on Ubuntu cloud VM image?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315502/how-to-disable-apt-daily-service-on-ubuntu-cloud-vm-image)

Answer (score -1):

This denotes that your package installer is being used by some another process.
Simplest way to get rid of this is to kill the init process i.e.

`kill -9 -1`

**Warning**

This will **log you out** killing all the processes, So Save for your current work 
*Not a efficient method but works..*