# Is it safe to disable apt-daily.service?

Tags: linux-mint, boot, apt, services

I use Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon.

I found this question indirectly relevant:
[How to disable `apt-daily.service` on Ubuntu cloud VM image?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315502/126755)

My question is: Is it safe to disable apt-daily.service?

Supposing I do system updates with an update script of mine.

---

```
$ systemd-analyze blame

11.027s apt-daily.service
 2.675s esets.service
  979ms netfilter-persistent.service
  638ms systemd-resolved.service
  634ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  592ms apt-daily-upgrade.service
  423ms dev-nvme0n1p2.device
  411ms vboxdrv.service
...
```

---

Addressing some comments:

- ***Safe*** in this context means something like: Would it abrupt some functions of my desktop system?
- I am concerned about the boot time, yes. It is fast, just could it be faster maybe...
- I use my own upgrade script since about 2 years ago, I am used to do the updates in CLI with that script by hand and I don't want any slow-downs due to `apt`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

apt-daily only does one thing by default: it downloads the list of installable/upgradable packages. If you turn it off, you'll need to run `apt update` (or equivalent) more frequently before upgrading or installing packages.

Nothing depends on apt-daily (you can check that `systemctl list-dependencies --reverse apt-daily` doesn't prevent anything else from starting), so it doesn't slow your boot process except by taking resources that other tasks may want. The only resource that apt-daily consumes is network bandwidth. This can take a while if there have been significant updates to the package list, but it's only a problem if your bandwidth is very limited and it's more important to have a lot of bandwidth available during the first few seconds after boot than at some other time.

`systemd-analyze blame` shows what takes a long time, but it doesn't show what the impact is. Since apt-daily doesn't block anything else, the fact that it takes a long time only has an impact on apt-daily itself, not on the rest of the functionality. `systemd-analyze critical-chain` is more useful if you're worried about boot time as in how long it takes for your computer to become useful.

So it's safe to turn off apt-daily, as long as you remember to run `apt update` before checking for upgrades, and you do this regularly without relying on any automatic notification that upgrades are available. But it isn't particularly useful.

Comment: `critical-chain` is far more useful than `blame` in most cases.